# Replace a \n in objects, which are in array

Tags: javascript

I want to replace \n which is in array of objects.
For now I came across this, but it replaces only string, not an actual '\n' which makes the line break.

```js
var obj = {
  'a': '\nThe fooman poured the drinks.',
  'b': {
    'c': 'Dogs say fook, but what does the fox say?'
  }
}

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\n/g, '')));
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: You can refer this link and get detailed answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049162/replace-character-in-array-of-objects thanks!

Comment: No, it didn't solved my problem, because I had to used regex epression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `\\n` in regax.

```js
var obj = {
   'a' : '\nThe fooman poured the drinks.',
   'b' : {
      'c' : 'Dogs say fook, but what does the fox say?'
   }
}

console.log (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n/g, '')));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add an another backslash (`\\`) to select the first one

```
console.log (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n/g, '')));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the escape back-slash to treat it like a literal back-slash.

Regex: `/\\n/g`

```js
var obj = {
  'a': '\nThe fooman poured the drinks.',
  'b': {
    'c': 'Dogs say fook, but what does the fox say?'
  }
}

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n/g, '')));
```